# HumHub Yii Update Table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

When I add a field to the database table `user` with the field `ip` for logging and displaying IPs, HumHub (based on Yii) is not able to fetch the newly added field in the database, and acts as if it is not defined.

I will get the output:

```
id 1
guid c3d6775e-08ca-49a4-93f2-8c3ed70bc867
wall_id 1
group_id 1
status 1
super_admin 1
username WASasquatch
email 
auth_mode local 
tags
language
last_activity_email 2015-02-15 06:43:21
last_login 2015-02-15 07:01:50
created_at 2015-02-15 06:43:21
created_by
updated_at 2015-02-25 00:25:42
updated_by 1
```

with

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {

    $updateIp = User::Model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    //$updateIp->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //$updateIp->update();

    foreach ($updateIp as $key => $field){
        echo '<b>'.$key.'</b> ' . $field . '<br />';
    }

}
```

Or I can render it with raw PHP and get

```
id 1
guid c3d6775e-08ca-49a4-93f2-8c3ed70bc867
wall_id 1
group_id 1
status 1
super_admin 1
username WASasquatch
email 
auth_mode local 
tags
language
last_activity_email 2015-02-15 06:43:21
last_login 2015-02-15 07:01:50
created_at 2015-02-15 06:43:21
created_by
updated_at 2015-02-25 00:25:42
updated_by 1
ip
```

Where the last field `ip` is present.

What is happening here?

Comment: Not aware of HumHub, but did you add `ip` in `User` model ? Or generated the model again from `gii` ?

Comment: I simply added the new ip row to the database. I know nothing of gii. Which is why I'm having a hard time believing a framework claiming they give **you** all the tools you need. xD Can't even skin the thing 100% because of CSS rendered past the theme CSS.

Comment: As far as I can see HumHub doesn't even come with Gii.